# How can I remove entries from a List that match values from a Set

Tags: java

I'd like to do something similar to

```
Collection.removeAll(Set);
```

but I'm using a `List<File>` and `Set<long>`

I've got a List of Files, and I'd like to remove any file from the list that contains one of the longs in my set as part of the filename.  I know I can do that if I iterate through the List of Files and do a compare to each entry in the set.  But that sounds horribly inefficient.

Again, I'd like to create a List of Files that does NOT contain any of the longs in my Set as part of the filename.

(for example)

```
List<File> filesFromDirectory;
filesFromDirectory.add(new File("first.123.file"));
filesFromDirectory.add(new File("second.456.file"));

Set<Long> fnameVals = HashSet<Long>();
fnameVals.add(456);
```

...

I'd like the result to be:

```
System.out.println(filesFromDirectory);

first.123.file
```

Comment: You can't beat what you described -- you do need to check each file and you do need to check each entry in the file! But that's not too bad algorithmically -- sets are amortised constant-time lookup.

Comment: Hmm, that is what I was afraid of.  Although I haven't looked at the way .removeAll works, but I suppose it'd be similar to what you've described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't written Java in aaaaages. This probably won't compile.

```
for(File f: filesFromDirectory) {
    bool OK = true;
    for(Long i: fnameVals) {
        if(f.name.contains(String.valueOf(i))) {
            OK = false;
            break;
    }
    if(OK) System.out.println(f.name);
}
```

Comment: Yes, although that is what I was trying to avoid by using the Collections.removeAll  Although as you pointed out, I'd have to do that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a regular expression out of the Longs in your set and then match the filenames against the (single) regular expression?

Comment: Yes, but I'd still need to iterate through the complete list comparing each long.  Using the regex instead of .contains

Comment: Doesn't sound efficient to me!

Comment: I like this idea since it removes a level of looping, but whether or not it is better depends on the sizes of you list and set.  In something trivial like your example, the overhead for making the regex and doing the matching should cost more than just comparing each file. If, in general, you had a longer list and a larger set, the regex might pay off - worth testing anyway.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a little confused.  How would this reduce a level of looping?

Comment: @VMcPherron because you'd have _one_ regex: `123|456|789|...`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.  Just concat all my longs together in one regex.  Would that really be very efficient if my set contains 300+ entries?

Comment: Although I would still need to iterate through my set to create my regex.  Suppose it'd be better though because it wouldn't be nested in my file iteration loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your file names like : {chars}*[0-9] * {chars}*
Number contained is unique(or you can implement a map algorithm for specific purpose)

How about this.  Iterate over file names store them in hash map with key as the number and value as entire string.
Iterate over set , for each value of set look in hash map, if object found remove it.
Please see : it will work only in pattern defined and unique keys (which could be achieved)
Also I am using iPad to answer so couldn't give answer in more details,sorry.. 
Don't like touchpad

Comment: I thought about something similar to that too.  Although I don't really want to create more objects than I need.  My guess is if I decided to go this way, I might be better off creating a long regex that contains all my longs and compare as I iterate over the file list.